# Get all possible positions around vector2 (for example 0;0) in range of X

Tags: c#, math, vector

I need to getall possible positions around vector2 (for example 0;0) in range of X

For example : start position (0;0)
In range of 1 - (0;1) (1;0) (-1;0) (0;-1)
In range of 2 - (0;1) (1;0) (-1;0) (0;-1) (-1;1) (-1;-1) (2;0) (0;2) (-2:0) (0;-2) etc.

I am confused )

Answer (score 0):

You could try nested for loops?

```
List<Vector2> list = new List<Vector2>();

Vector2 mid = new Vector2(0,0)
float range = 2;

for (int i=mid.x-range; i<=mid.x+range; i+=1)
{
    for (int j=mid.y-range; j<=mid.y+range; j+=1)
    {
        Vector2 target = new Vector2(i,j);
        float distance = Vector2.Distance(mid, target);
        if (distance < range) {
            list.Add(target);
        }
    }
}
```